# How can I summarize data across all records in a report?

Tags: cognos, cognos-8

I have a report with *section* footers summarizing a count of data items in each section. I'd also like an *overall* footer with a count of all items on the *entire report*.

I'm currently using

```
 count([Value] for [Grouped Value])
```

This is how I can get aggregate function information for grouped *sections* but it doesn't seem to work in the overall footer; it outputs the count of items in the last group, not all items in the report.

How can I summarize/aggregate information for a *whole report* in Cognos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression you need for the data item in the overall footer to get full-report summary information is `for report`:

```
 count([Value] for report)
```

If you're using Cognos 8 the `for report` component is already in the Data Item Expression list under Components:

[image: Data item expression list]

I figured this out from [Cognos Summary Functions](http://www.itap.purdue.edu/ea/files/UnderstandingTheCognosSummaryFunctions.pdf).